# Uncaught type error is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I have this

```
<p> Deseja inserir esta amostra numa experiencia? <input type="checkbox" id="showdivs" onclick="showdivs()"</input><p>

<script>
        function showdivs() {
            var yourUl = document.getElementById("tryok");
            yourUl.style.display = yourUl.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
            var yourU2 = document.getElementById("tryok2");
            yourU2.style.display = yourU2.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
        }
</script>
```

I wish that everytime the input is checked, some divs appear/disappear.
But I am having an error on the chrome console: uncaught type error showdivs is not a function...

Obviously i am doing something wrong. I am initiating html/css/javascript learning have no idea whats wrong could someone help me out?

Comment: You don't appear to have your function inside `<script>` tags, so your `onclick` won't be able to find it.

Comment: I do have it inside a script tag, i just didnt show in the code. will edit

Comment: You might want to fix your tags. You have two `<p>` start tags without end tags, your input element is missing a closing bracket and an input tag can't have an end tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the javascript above the `HTML`, or add your JavaScript to some kind of page load.

Example:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  // ADD CODE
});
```

Your JavaScript should be working when included correctly as seen in here:

```js
function showdivs() {
    var yourUl = document.getElementById("tryok");
    yourUl.style.display = yourUl.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
    var yourU2 = document.getElementById("tryok2");
    yourU2.style.display = yourU2.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none';
}
```

```html
<p> Deseja inserir esta amostra numa experiencia? <input type="checkbox" id="showdivs" onclick="showdivs()"</input></p>
<div id="tryok"><p>UI1</p></div>
<div id="tryok2"><p>UI2</p></div>
```

Comment: idk whats going on i have it like that and it doesnt seem to work

Comment: @PedroMartins its because of the order in which you include your JavaScript. Put your `script` tag at the top of your page, or wrap it in that event listener

Comment: Oh... I see now it works lol thanks